# ARM template for enabling/disabling CosmosDB autoscaler on existing container

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

There are [multiple ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-provision-autoscale-throughput?tabs=api-async) how to create a new CosmosDB container with enabled autoscaler including [ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-sql-with-resource-manager#azure-cosmos-account-with-autoscale-throughput).

Is there a way to switch the throughput mode back and forth on the existing container using ARM templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the only way to do this is via the Azure Portal. The ability to do this via PowerShell or Azure CLI should be available in July 2020.

Currently there is not a way to do this with ARM templates and because it is not possible to both migrate from standard provisioned throughput to autoscale throughput and also set the throughput amount (RU/s) it is impossible to do this migration with a single operation using an ARM template. This is something we will look to enable in the future but for now and short term, Portal, PowerShell and CLI will be the only options.

Thanks.